# Why is the dielectric strength decreasing with thickness

Tags: electric-fields, electrical-resistance, dielectric

I wonder why the dielectric strength is higher the thinner the material is:

> "Dielectric films tend to exhibit greater dielectric strength than
> thicker samples of the same material."

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength#Breakdown_field_strength)

In the german article there is also an equation given: $ E = U / d $.
Given that, I can simply understand it. But I wonder about the phenomenon itself or why the equation is valid. Or at least for me, it isn't obvious that the dielectric strength will decrease over thickness. When I compare it with radiation like gammas, it is quite vice versa.

Comment: Perhaps check the definition of "dielectric **strength**"  vs.  the total standoff voltage capability?  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength for a clear explanation

Comment: I'm not sure if I got that hint but do you mean I mix voltage and electric field? Which is valid anyway: The necessary voltage to breakthrough increases with the thickness..   and the E-field decreases with the thickness.
Yeah, that makes sense now..  or? :)

Comment: I have to admit it is still Greek to me. I mean I understand the dispute but it's not intuitive that a material has a higher dielectric strength the thinner it's isolation is...  Given that it would be best if there would be only a layer of atoms. And I'm safe. But when I replace that one layer of atoms with a 10m thick wall, the voltage will break through.
That is totally intuitive..  and when I even replace that single layer of atoms with - hypothetically - a layer of quarks, it is even way higher...

Comment: Given a dielectric strength of 1kV/1cm, I need a voltage of 10 kV either I am 10 cm away or 0.1cm away.
That is so weird..